# Best way to Sort lists in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two lists, one containing all possible values of an enum in a special order (list A) and a second one which is filled with some of these enum values/or null/or all (list B) but the order is random.

What I am trying is to sort list B in the order of list A. When values are missing, they are skipped, but the order should stay the same.

In the first instance, I thought this is easy but I can‘t manage it without a mess of code and I think this could be done way easier.

Comment: I think you may change the title compare>> sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add items in secondList that exists in firstList
this function will do so..

```
List getMatchingItems() {
  List newSortedList = [];
  List<String> firstList = [
    "ENUM1",
    "ENUM2",
    "ENUM3",
    "ENUM4",
  ];
  List<String> secondList = [
    "ENUM2",
    "ENUM4",
    "ENUM5",
  ];

  for (var ennum in secondList) {
    if (firstList.contains(ennum)) {
      newSortedList.add(ennum);
    }
  }
  return newSortedList;
}
```